# MySQL SHOW CREATE TRIGGER trigger name- Only return one column

Tags: mysql

In MySQL when I run the syntax `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name` the result is a table with the columns `Trigger`, `sql_mode`, `SQL Original Statement`, etc.

I only want the result to be SQL Original Statement. Is there a way to just return this one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table instead:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('CREATE DEFINER =`',DEFINER,'` TRIGGER ', TRIGGER_NAME ,' ', ACTION_TIMING, ' ', EVENT_MANIPULATION, ' ON `', EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, '` FOR EACH ', ACTION_ORIENTATION, ' ', ACTION_STATEMENT ) `trigger`
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = 'tgrAddSongPlay';
```

Comment: Unfortunately ACTION_STATEMENT is missing some key information I need/want for recreating a trigger. 

SQL Original Statement is exactly what I need/want. Using SHOW CREATE TRIGGER trigger name return every column name which I can use. I was just curious if there was a way to pull only the info I need. 

Thanks for answering!

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I don't quite understand why this works I will need to do some more research on this syntax.

Again I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem. I would think SHOW CREATE TRIGGER uses INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS behind the scenes